# How can I divide a number while giving duplicates?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, divisibility

I have $1000$ colors, and I want to divide these colors among $5$ people such that each color is given to at least $3$ people. How much should I give each user such that each color is given to at least $3$ people and each user gets the least number of colors while doing a fair distribution? Is there a general formula that I can use?

for example, if we have 8 colors: $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8$ and $5$ users

user 1: 1,2,3,6,7,8

user 2: 3,4,5,1,2,3

user 3: 3,4,5,1,2,3

user 4: 6,7,8,3,4,5

user 5: 6,7,8,3,4,5

Comment: Not sure the rules are clear.  You can give each color to as many people as you like (provided at least $3$ people get each color)?  If so, there are lots and lots of ways to do it.  Are you asking for the number of such ways to do it?

Comment: To count the methods, just do each color separately and multiply.  to do one color, count separately the number of ways to give the color to exactly $3$, exactly $4$, and exactly $5$ people.

Comment: @lulu I am asking about how much should I give each user such that each color is given to at least 3 people. I updated the question.

Comment: There's no unique answer to that.  You can give each person all $1000$ colors if you want.   You can each of the first three people all $1000$ colors, and nothing for the other two people.  You can give the first $500$ colors to people $A,B,C$ and the second $500$ to people $C,D,E$.  And many, many other options.

Comment: @lulu I want the users to get the most fair distribution. So they should get approximately the same number

Comment: There is nothing about that in your post.  Please edit.  Note that if we give everybody all $1000$ colors then they each have exactly the same number.

Comment: @lulu updated, Thank you for the advice

Comment: Note that $\frac {3000}5=600$.  I'd give the first person $\{C_1, \cdots, C_{600}\}$, the second person $\{C_{601}, \cdots, C_{200}\}$ where I am writing the colors cyclicly (so the color after $C_{1000}$ is $C_1$).  Then give the third person $\{C_{201}, \cdots, C_{800}\}$ and so on.

Comment: Maybe easier to think of it this way:  Write the $1000$ colors down in a line three times, so the line is $3000$ terms long.  Give $A$ the first $600$, give $B$ the second $300$, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that you want to distribute the minimum so that each color is distributed to at least $3$ people.

As has been commented, the problem is trivial (i.e. where you could give all $1000$ colors to persons 1 through 3, ignoring persons 4 and 5), unless you **add the constraint** that each person receives the same number of colors.

The following charted solution solves the problem, *as I am interpreting it* : each person gets the same number of colors.

---

Consider $~\displaystyle \binom{5}{3} = 10.$  This represents the number of ways of selecting $5$ items, without replacement, where order of selection is deemed irrelevant.  These $10$ selections are represented in the chart below.

Consider for the moment, the simpler problem of $10$ colors, to be given to $5$ people, as charted below.

\begin{array}{| l | l | l | l | l | l |}
  \hline                       
\text{Color} & \text{Person 1} & \text{Person 2} & \text{Person 3} & \text{Person 4} & \text{Person 5} \\
  \hline                       
  1 & x & x & x & & \\
  \hline 
  2 & x & x & & x & \\
  \hline 
  3 & x & x & & & x \\
  \hline 
  4 & x & & x & x & \\
  \hline 
  5 & x & & x & & x \\
  \hline
  6 & x & & & x & x \\
  \hline 
  7 & & x & x & x & \\
  \hline 
  8 & & x & x & & x \\
  \hline 
  9 & & x & & x & x \\
  \hline 
  10 & & & x & x & x \\
  \hline  
\end{array}

In distributing $10$ colors to $5$ people, so that each color is distributed to at least $3$ people, you must make a minimum of $10 \times 3 = 30$ [color-person] distributions.

Therefore, the above chart represents the minimum, for $10$ colors.

Since $10$ is a factor of $1000$, you simply repeat the above chart $100$ times, to achieve the minimum [color:person] distribution.

For example, each of the following colors would be given specifically to persons $~1,~2~$ and $~3,~$ **only**: 
color-1, color-11,color-21, ..., color-991.